# Python Matpolotlib error while using contourf

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I am trying to execute the following program and the I am receiving the warning at the end of the result. Please educate me regarding the error.

"/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/collections.py:548: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  if self._edgecolors == 'face':"

```
        import numpy as np
        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

        colorinterpolation = 50
        colourMap = plt.cm.jet

        x =  input('Number of nodes in the vertical axis: ')
        y =  input('Number of nodes in the horizontal axis: ')
        TI = input('Initial tempertature: ')
        TN = input('Northern boundary temperature: ')
        TS = input('Southern boundary temperature: ')
        TE = input('Eastern boundary temperature: ')
        TW = input('Western boundary temperature: ')
        t  = input('Number of time steps needed: ')
        C1 = input('Courant number in x direction: ')
        C2 = input('Courant number in y direction: ')
        C3 = 1 - (2*C1) - (2*C2)

        T = np.zeros((x, y))
        T.fill(TI)
        print 'Time step 0'
        print T
        for timestep in range(1, t+1):
            T[:1, :] = TN
            T[x-1:, :] = TS
            T[:, :1] = TW
            T[:, y-1:] = TE 
            print 'Time step', timestep 
            for j in range(1, y-1, 1):
                for i in range(1, x-1, 1):
                    T[i, j] = T[i, j]*C3 + C1*(T[i+1,j] + T[i-1, j]) + C2*(T[i, j+1] + T[i, j-1])
            print T

       plt.contourf(np.flipud(T), colorinterpolation, cmap=colourMap)
       plt.title('2-D transient heat conduction')
       plt.colorbar()
       plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mind that this is not actually an error, just a warning. So you can ignore it, if otherwise everything works as expected. It could be caused by some mismatch in between versions, see e.g. [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/5209/)

You may consider updating numpy and matplotlib if you really aim at getting rid of this warning.